# How to decode Google::Apis::AdminDirectoryV1::UserPhoto.photo_data

Tags: ruby, rubygems, google-api-client

For google-api-client gem version 0.19.4 I try to fetch all users and their photos using Google::Apis::AdminDirectoryV1.

When i fetch user photo (Google::Apis::AdminDirectoryV1::UserPhoto) using photo_data field i get a hex string. I unable to covert it to an image?

How do i convert the data into image. Couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

as stated in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Admin_1_1Directory_1_1directory__v1_1_1Data_1_1UserPhoto.html) that field is base64 encoded.

use base64 as in the example:

```
require "base64"

enc   = Base64.encode64('Send reinforcements')
                    # -> "U2VuZCByZWluZm9yY2VtZW50cw==\n"
plain = Base64.decode64(enc)
                    # -> "Send reinforcements"
```